# Индекс находился вне границ массива. Укажите ошибку

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Проблема указана в коде, помогите исправить

```
procedure PutInQue(var Que: string; arg: char);
begin
  Que := Que + arg; { добавляем в конец строки }
end;
{ Выбор из очереди Que элемента в параметр arg }
function GetFromQue(var Que: string; var arg: char): boolean;
begin
  if Length(Que) = 0 { если очередь пуста }
    then GetFromQue := false
  else begin
    GetFromQue := true; { если не пуста }
    arg := Que[1]; { запоминаем первый элемент }
    Delete(Que, 1, 1); { и удаляем его из очереди }
  end
end;

var
  S_IN: string; { входной поток – символы }
  S_OUT: string; { выходной поток (пары) }
  all: string;
  c1, c2: char; { очередная пара – символы строки }
  i: integer;{ индекс во входном потоке }

begin
  S_IN := 'ZHJKqwertASDyuiopQWERTYUIOPasdf';
  S_OUT := '';
  all := ''; 
  for i := 1 to Length(S_IN) do
  begin
    c1 := S_IN[i];
    if c1 in ['A'..'Z']
    then begin
      if GetFromQue(all, c2)  then 
          begin
        if (all[length(all)] in ['a'..'z']) then //Тут выдаёт: Индекс находился вне границ массива
          S_OUT := (S_OUT + c1 + c2 + ' ')
      end
      else PutInQue(all, c1);
    end
    else begin
      if GetFromQue(all, c2)

        then if(all[length(all)] in ['A'..'Z']) then
          S_OUT := S_OUT + c2 + c1 + ' '

        else PutInQue(all, c1);
    end
  end;
  Writeln('Входной поток:');
  Writeln(S_IN);
  Writeln('Выходной поток:');
  Writeln(S_OUT);
end. 

 1. Элемент списка
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавил протокол в код для вывода на экран. Смотрите: вы помещаете в очередь 1 символ, потом его же забираете и очередь пуста. Вообще в таких случаях надо использовать пошаговую отладку.

```
1 перед GetFromQue all= 
2 начало цикла all= Z
2 перед GetFromQue all= Z
2 после GetFromQue all=
```

Можно добавить проверку очереди на пустоту. Но вообще, кажется, у вас неверная реализация алгоритма решения задачи. Но поскольку условия задачи нет, то более определённо сказать нельзя.

```
procedure PutInQue(var Que: string; arg: char);
begin
  Que := Que + arg; { добавляем в конец строки }
end;
{ Выбор из очереди Que элемента в параметр arg }
function GetFromQue(var Que: string; var arg: char): boolean;
begin
  if Length(Que) = 0 { если очередь пуста }
    then GetFromQue := false
  else begin
    GetFromQue := true; { если не пуста }
    arg := Que[1]; { запоминаем первый элемент }
    Delete(Que, 1, 1); { и удаляем его из очереди }
  end
end;

var
  S_IN: string; { входной поток – символы }
  S_OUT: string; { выходной поток (пары) }
  all: string;
  c1, c2: char; { очередная пара – символы строки }
  i: integer;{ индекс во входном потоке }

begin
  S_IN := 'ZHJKqwertASDyuiopQWERTYUIOPasdf';
  S_OUT := '';
  all := ''; 
  for i := 1 to Length(S_IN) do
  begin
    writeln(i,' начало цикла all= ',all);
    c1 := S_IN[i];
    if c1 in ['A'..'Z']
    then begin
      writeln(i,' перед GetFromQue all= ',all);
      if GetFromQue(all, c2)  then 
          begin
      writeln(i,' после GetFromQue all= ',all);
       if all.Length>0 then 
        if (all[all.Length] in ['a'..'z']) then //Тут выдаёт: Индекс находился вне границ массива
          S_OUT := (S_OUT + c1 + c2 + ' ')
      end
      else PutInQue(all, c1);
    end
    else begin
      if GetFromQue(all, c2) then 
      if all.Length>0 then 
      if(all[all.Length] in ['A'..'Z']) then
          S_OUT := S_OUT + c2 + c1 + ' '

        else PutInQue(all, c1);
    end
  end;
  Writeln('Входной поток:');
  Writeln(S_IN);
  Writeln('Выходной поток:');
  Writeln(S_OUT);
end.
```

Кроме того более правильно для получения длины обращаться к свойству Length строки.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут:

```pascal
IF (all[Length(all)] IN ['a'..'z']) THEN
```

Вы не учитываете, что длина `all` может быть `0`.

Comment: Перед неё идёт функция GetFromQue, которая выдаёт false, если all=0 и,  если all=0, то программа просто туда не зайдёт

Comment: @ВладАпухтин  Вы забыли, что она также удаляет элемент.  Если длина была `1`, то станет `0`.